# Rake - Don't know how to build task 'build'

Tags: rake

Apologies for a vague question. I haven't used Rake before and am trying to figure it out.

I'm trying to run tests with rake but I get this stack trace when I do.

```
rake test:all --trace
** Invoke test:all (first_time)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'build'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:57:in `lookup_prerequisite'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:53:in `block in prerequisite_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:53:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:53:in `prerequisite_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:all
```

What's the issue here? Is it likely something like a missing dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake api` is the command I required.